# Prove $f(x,y)=\frac{x-y}{x^2+y^2}$ is integrable on $(0,1)^2$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral

So It is continuous on the given square and measurable so I just need to show that the integral of positive - integral of negative part is finiate. SO  $\int_0^1\int_0^x|\frac{x-y}{x^2+y^2}|+\int_0^1\int_x^1|\frac{x-y}{x^2+y^2}|<\infty$ I can evaluate this but it gets ugly and I am pretty sure there is some better approach and I have a feeling that 
$\int_{(0,1)^2}f(x,y)=0$, because the second part of the question asks to calculate this integral

Comment: Then why don’t you try showing that $\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$ is integrable on the square. You can directly compute the integral without taking absolute value because the integrand is anyway positive on the square. Then by symmetry so is $\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$ and the integrals are equal. If $g,h \in L^1$ so is $g-h$ because $L^1$ is a vector space, and $\int g-h = \int g - \int h$. This confirms your claim that $\int f= 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In polar coordinates, the integrand is $\frac{\cos(\theta)-\sin(\theta)}{r}$. When integrating with polar coordinates, there is a factor of $r$ in the $dA$. So in polar coordinates, this is $$\iint_{\text{unit square}}\left(\cos(\theta)-\sin(\theta)\right)\,dr\,d\theta.$$
This line at $x=1$ is $r=\sec(\theta)$ in polar coordinates, and the line $y=1$ is $r=\csc(\theta)$. So this can be calculated as

\begin{align*}&\int_{\theta=0}^{\pi/4}\int_{r=0}^{\sec(\theta)}\left(\cos(\theta)-\sin(\theta)\right)\,dr\,d\theta + \int_{\theta=\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\int_{r=0}^{\csc(\theta)}\left(\cos(\theta)-\sin(\theta)\right)\,dr\,d\theta \\
=& \int_{\theta=0}^{\pi/4}\left(1-\tan(\theta)\right)\,d\theta + \int_{\theta=\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\left(\cot(\theta)-1\right)\,d\theta\end{align*}

These are both finite integrals but I'll leave it to you to conclude with their explicit values, and see that they cancel out.